# How to run Android without installing the APK everytime?

Tags: android-studio

Launching a project would be much faster if Android Studio wouldn't need to reinstall the APK everytime.

Is there a solution/tool for this?

Thank u all.

Answer (score 2):

Use Android **Instant Run**.

> Android Studio sets up new projects to deploy to the Android Emulator or a connected device with just a few clicks. Once your app is installed, Instant Run allows you to push code changes without building a new APK.

Check out the [Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html) to find out more.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the apk once then you can directly run it on the connected device using the follow option, just click the icon on the right side of **run** option. See the image for reference. if there is any difficulty write in comment.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1L6U.png